# error con Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\UNITEC\registro.php on line 11

Tags: php, xampp

Buenas noches toy realizando una verificación de correos a traves de PHP con MARIADB, pero me guarda los usuarios sin validarme si el correo del registro existe o no: Anexo el codigo muchas gracias.

```
<?php

    $realname=$_POST['realname'];
    $mail=$_POST['nick'];
    $pass= $_POST['pass'];
    $rpass=$_POST['rpass'];

    require("conexion.php");

    $checkemail=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$mail'");
    $check_mail=mysqli_num_rows($checkemail);
        if($pass==$rpass){
            if($check_mail>0){
                echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Atencion, ya existe el mail designado para un usuario, verifique sus datos");</script> ';
            }else{


                mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO login VALUES('$realname','$pass','$mail')");
                //echo 'Se ha registrado con exito';
                echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Usuario registrado con éxito");</script> ';

            }

        }else{
            echo 'Las contraseñas son incorrectas';
        }


?>
```

el error al registrar me dice Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\UNITEC\registro.php on line 11

Comment: Intenta de esta manera: $checkemail=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='" . $mail ."'");

Comment: hola gracias por el apoyo, realice la modificacion como me menciono, pero el error continua  de igual forma me guarda el usuario sin validar el mail y dando este error al final igual

Answer (score 0):

Usa mejor consultas preparadas y con ello generas el resultado:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_params("s",$mail);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    if($result){
       /*USUARIO EXISTENTE*/
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO login VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_params("sss",$realname,$pass,$mail);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if($result){
       /*USUARIO REGISTRADO*/
    }

    /*USUARIO NO REGISTRADO*/
?>
```

Considera que `$con` es tu conexion y que la debes abrir y cerrar entre cada consulta por cuestiones de seguridad, tambien con consultas preparadas evitas inyecciones SQL.